# PHP lookup based on key or data

Tags: php, data-structures, lookup-tables

```
Key | Data
----------
 1  |  A
 2  |  B
 3  |  C
```

Is there a data structure that allows me to lookup the data when given the key, or to lookup the key when given the data?  I'm working in PHP, but I'm curious about answers for any language.

Comment: You mean, a data structure that maps both Key to Data and Data to Key?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have it in an array..

```
$array = array('1'=>'A','2'=>'B','3'=>'C');

//Use the key to get the value
echo $array['1'] //Echos A
echo $array['2'] //Echos B
echo $array['3'] //Echos C

//Use the value to get the key
echo array_search('A',$array) //Echos 1
echo array_search('B',$array) //Echos 2
echo array_search('C',$array) //Echos 3
```

Comment: Not a perfect answer to my question, but it does solve the problem I'm having.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If it's an array in PHP, and you want to get the data based on the key, you can use [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) , or if you want the key based on the data, I *think* you'd have to loop over the array

```
$myArray = array('key1' => 'var','key2' => 'test');
$data = 'test';
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $data) {
        echo 'Found it - ' . $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the data is an exact match, you could also use `array_search()`. As for partial matches, looping would be the only way.

Comment: Ah I never knew about that function, that seems a lot simpler (and more efficient?) than looping over. Thank you!

Comment: using a built in php function will always be faster (more efficient) than making your own. The difference will be minimal, but it is basically that php is compiled c compared to having php interpret/parse/execute your own code.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) as dictionaries.

Your example could be coded as:

```
<?php $arr = array("1" => "A", "2" => "B", "3" => "C"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A lookup table will offer you the best performance if you use keys as the reference point.  If the data structure leads to value referencing such as `in_array()` or `array_search()` or any full array scan, this will not perform very well.

Accessing the lookup data by key (checking its existence before trying to access it) via `isset()`, `key_exists()`, `array_key_exists()`, or the null coalescing operator will always outperform value-based referencing.

With regard to `isset()` and the null coalescing operator, notice that when the  value accessed is `null`, these technique treat the value as "not found/set" because they look for declared variables with non-null values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Xceh3))

```
$array = ['1' => 'A', '2' => null, '3' => 0];

foreach (['1', '2', '3', '4'] as $test) {
    var_export(isset($array[$test]) ? $array[$test] : '-');
    echo " , ";
    var_export(key_exists($test, $array) ? $array[$test] : '-');
    echo " , ";
    var_export(array_key_exists($test, $array) ? $array[$test] : '-');
    echo " , ";
    var_export($array[$test] ?? '-');
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'A' , 'A' , 'A' , 'A'
'-' , NULL , NULL , '-'
0 , 0 , 0 , 0
'-' , '-' , '-' , '-'
```