# Use values from array as switch-case keys

Tags: php, switch-statement

I’m working on an app, and I’m stuck.

I want to do `foreach` inside `switch` like this:

```
<?PHP
$gtid = $_GET['id'];
// ID(key) => value
$dbs  = array(
    "ZTI10" => "Example1",
    "O1JTQ" => "Example2",
    "4V1OR" => "Example3"
);

switch($gtid){

foreach ($dbs as $key => $value) {

    case $key:
        echo "On ID $key is $value";
        break;

  }
}
?>
```

Is that even possible? Or is there any other way to do what I want here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [PHP lookup based on key or data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71816284/2943403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if doesn't even need a loop

```
if (isset($dbs[$_GET['id']])) {
    echo sprintf('On ID %s is %s', $_GET['id'], $dbs[$_GET['id']]);
}
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. Use a simple `if` statement inside your `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach ($dbs as $key => $value) {
    if ($gtid == $key) {
        echo "On ID $key is $value";
        break;
  }
}
```

The [`break`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) here causes the execution to immediately jump out of the `foreach` loop, so it won't evaluate any other elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Easy way to do this:

```
<?php

$gtid = $_GET['id'];

$dbs  = array(
    "ZTI10" => "Example1",
    "O1JTQ" => "Example2",
    "4V1OR" => "Example3"
);

if ( isset($dbs[$gtid]) ) {
    echo "On ID $gtid is $dbs[$gtid]";
} else {
    // default
}

?>
```